# Long responsive title on a single line HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I work on a responsive website. I have some long titles like "Savez-vous vraiment ce qu'il se passe sur le terrain ?".

The goal is that the title will always stay on a single line, regardless of the resolution and the behavior of Bootstrap.

I could do that with `white-space:no-wrap` but the title will not be in the center anymore...

I don't see another solution than reduce font-size in function of different resolutions.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: What if it goes on two lines? What are the undesired consequences in that case?

Comment: http://fittextjs.com/ not sure, because of specific request (always in one line) but maybe this plugin could help... Btw, on small mobile screens text could be unreadable, if you decrease font size too much (i would break it in two or more lines)...

Comment: Is there something positioned absolutely under that heading so that it must stay single line?

Comment: Yes on mobile phone it will be unreadable ^^ The goal is for laptop and desktop resolutions :)

Comment: Thanks for fittextjs, i think it will help me :)

Comment: Another reccomendation for fittext.js, I've used it for this exact problem many times. Adjust the compressor to taste and it should give you exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You could have wrap a div around your title and use text-align: center

```
<div class="titlewrapper">
    <div>Savez-vous vraiment ce qu'il se passe sur le terrain ?</div>
</div>

.titlewrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it will do wordbreak when reduce the size of the browser or resolution

Comment: to prevent the wrapping see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679804/prevent-wrapping-of-containers-span-or-div

Answer (score 0):

If you roughly know the maximum length of a title, you could use the [`vw` unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths), which means percent of width. It's [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=vw) by most modern browsers.

For your string, this would look something like this:

```
h1 {
    font-size: 3vw;
}
```

[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1kp5bfq9/)