# How to prevent label text from go to new line and display only one line?

Tags: html, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I work on asp.net mvc i face issue label text display on two lines

but expected is display on one line .

I need label text display without go new line as Last working day it must display also on one line

another features also with red line must be display on one line

example

```
resignation
submition
date
```

Expected it must display

```
resignation summation date
```

CSS attributes

```
   .employee-info {
       display: flex;
       justify-content: space-around;
   }

  

   .table-border-end {
       height: 50px;
       border-top: 2px solid gray;
       border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
   }

   label {
       display: block;
       font-weight: bold;
       margin-bottom: 5px;
   }

   

   label {
       display: block;
       margin-top: 8px;
       font-weight: bold;
   }

   .requestInfo {
       padding-top: 5px;
   }

   .flex {
       display: flex;
   }

   .requestInfo-flex-div-1 {
       width: 37mm;
   }

   

   .requestInfo-flex-div-4 {
       width: 63mm;
       border-bottom: solid 1px black;
       text-align: center;
       margin-left: 5px;
   }

   

   .requestInfo-flex-div-6 {
       width: 40mm;
       border-bottom: solid 1px black;
       text-align: center;
       margin-left: 5px;
   }

   .modelData {
       font-size: 12px;
   }
```

my script as below :

```
<table>
           <tr>
               <td style="width:200px;padding-left:60px;">
                   <label>Emp. ID:</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:300px;">
                   <label class="requestInfo-flex-div-6 modelData">@Model.EmpID</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:200px;">
                   <label for="dept-branch">:الرقم الوظيفى</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:700px;">
               </td>
               <td style="width:200px;">
                   <label>Emp.Name:</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:300px;">
                   <label class="requestInfo-flex-div-4 modelData">@Model.EmpName</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:200px;">
                   <label for="emp-sign">:اسم الموظف</label>
               </td>

           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td style="width:200px;padding-left:60px;">
                   <label>Dept./Branch:</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:300px;">
                   <label class="requestInfo-flex-div-4 modelData">@Model.Dept</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:200px;">
                   <label>:الفرع/لاداره</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:700px;">
               </td>
               <td style="width:200px;">
                   <label>Designation :</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:300px;">
                   <label class="requestInfo-flex-div-4 modelData">@Model.Designation</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:200px;">
                   <label for="emp-sign">:المسمى الوظيفى</label>
               </td>

           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td style="width:200px;padding-left:60px;">
                   <label>Resignation Submittion Date:</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:300px;">
                   <label class="requestInfo-flex-div-4 modelData">@Model.ResignationSubmissionDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:200px;">
                   <label for="dept-branch">:تاريخ تقديم الاستقاله</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:700px;">
               </td>
               <td style="width:200px;">
                   <label>Mobile No:</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:300px;">
                   <label class="requestInfo-flex-div-4 modelData">@Model.MobileNo</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:200px;margin-right:10px;">
                   <label for="emp-sign">:رقم الهاتف</label>
               </td>

           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td style="width:200px;padding-left:60px;">
                   <label>Employee Sign:</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:300px;">
                   <label class="requestInfo-flex-div-4 modelData"></label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:200px;">
                   <label for="emp-sign">:توقيع الموظف</label>
               </td>
           
               <td style="width:700px;">
               </td>

               <td style="width:200px;">
                   <label for="emp-id">Last Working Day:</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:300px;">
                   <label class="requestInfo-flex-div-4 modelData">@Model.LastWorkingDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</label>
               </td>
               <td style="width:200px;margin-right:10px;">
                   <label for="dept-branch">:اخر يوم عمل</label>
               </td>

           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td style="width:200px;padding-left:60px;">
                   <label for="emp-id">The Reason of Resignation: </label>
               </td>

          
               <td colspan="5" style="padding-bottom: 2px;">
                   @Model.Reason
                   <hr style="border: none; border-top: 1px solid black; margin: 2px 0;">
               </td>
            
               <td style="width:200px;">
                   <label for="emp-sign">:سبب الاستقاله</label>
               </td>

           </tr>


       </table>
```

my issue on features with red line

[image: red line features]

**Updated post**
I accept no wrap but i don't know how to apply it

can you show to me no wrap with my sample

and are i will change width or not

can you show me please

Comment: [`text-wrap: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-wrap)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent wrapping of span or div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679804/prevent-wrapping-of-span-or-div)

Comment: can i modify table above to prevent label on every line from go new line

Comment: can i use any thing instead of using no wrap i need another solution with help sample please

Comment: [Edit] your question to show how you applied the answers to the duplicate to your situation and/or add an explanation of why `nowrap` does not work for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can force your text to be one line by adding `white-space: nowrap;` in your CSS.

For example: for your whole HTML page :

```
html {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: so i will make not wrape only without change width of every label that is what you mean

Comment: This is exactly what the answers of the proposed duplicate say. Do not copy the answers of another question to this question. If you see a comment starting with "Does this answer your question?" underneath a question, follow the link presented. If the answers there answer the question, do not answer the original question.